# Output parameter in stored procedure in EF

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-4, output-parameter

I have an existing database with lots of complex stored procedure and I want to use those procedure through EF 4. I have done the following:

1. Created an EF data object, `Customer`.
2. Added a Stored Procedure into the EF
3. Right Click on the EF designer and add a function import.
4. Function Import Name - `MyFunction`, complex type.

Resulting code:

```
CustomerEntities entity = new CustomerEntities();
var result = entity.MyFunction("XYZ", ref o_MyString);
```

Now my stored procedure has an output parameter which I used to call by the ref (in WebForm). But I am getting the below error:

> cannot convert from 'ref string' to
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter'

Please help

**Edit**

When I am trying to save I am getting the below error

> A mapping function binding specifies a function Model.Store.P_GetCustomer with an unsupported parameter: o_MyString. Output parameters may only be mapped through the RowsAffectedParameter property. Use result bindings to return values from a function invocation.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Output parameters are returned in `ObjectParameter` instance. So you must use code like:

```
var oMyString = new ObjectParameter("o_MyString", typeof(string));
var result = ctx.MyFunction("XYZ", oMyString).ToList();
var data = oMyString.Value.ToString();
```

The reason is that function import cannot use ref parameter because output parameter is not filled until you process result set from the database = if you don't call `ToList` or iterate the result of the stored procedure the output parameter is null.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried the same But the issue still persist. I am able to run the application but when I going to the desired URL I am getting the same error message in edmx file.

Comment: What type is your output parameter in the stored procedure?

Comment: It's a string, simply returns the insert, update status with table name and other related info. NVARCHAR(1000)

Comment: That is strange - it should work. Is it stored procedure mapped to insert or update of the entity?

Comment: This may help: [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2011/09/23/using-entity-framework-code-first-with-stored-procedures-that-have-output-parameters.aspx) or this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896334.aspx)

Comment: Ladislav, what if I don't need an output resultset? I would like retrieve output parameter only, because in my case stored procedure doesn't return a resulset. Can I read output parameter value?

Comment: Exactly Rudolf.
One of the most absurd things I've seen in the realm of ORM.
If all I want is the output parameters, I shouldn't have to process the results set (when there isn't one).

Answer (score 2):

[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896334(v=vs.100).aspx) suggests the following:

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetDepartmentName
>      @ID INT ,
>      @Name NVARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
> AS
>      SELECT   @Name = Name
>      FROM     Department
>      WHERE    DepartmentID = @ID
> ```

Solution

> ```
> using (SchoolEntities context = new SchoolEntities())
> {
>    // name is an output parameter.
>
>    ObjectParameter name = new ObjectParameter("Name", typeof(String));
>    context.GetDepartmentName(1, name);
>    Console.WriteLine(name.Value);
> }
> ```