# EF Code First SP with out parameter

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-code-first, out-parameters

I have the function

```
    public IEnumerable<OrderDtoGet> GetLookupOrders(Int64 productId, TableParameters param, Boolean showCompletedOnly, Boolean showDebug, PagingParameters pagingParam)
    {
        var outParam = new SqlParameter("@TotalRows", 0) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };

         return UnitOfWork.Context.Database.SqlQuery<OrderDtoGet>("GetOrdersLookup @productId, @showCompletedOnly, @showDebug, @sortField, @searchField, @sortDirect, @TotalRows out, @page, @pagesize",
            new SqlParameter("@productID", productId),
            new SqlParameter("@showCompletedOnly", showCompletedOnly),
            new SqlParameter("@showDebug", showDebug),
            new SqlParameter("@sortField", param.SortField),
            new SqlParameter("@searchField", param.SearchField),
            new SqlParameter("@sortDirect", param.SortDirect),
            outParam,
            new SqlParameter("@page", pagingParam.currentPage),
            new SqlParameter("@pagesize", pagingParam.numberOfEntriesPerPage));

    }
```

and I have next SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetOrdersLookup]
        @productId int ,
        @showCompletedOnly bit ,
        @showDebug bit,
        @sortField nvarchar(200) ,
        @searchField nvarchar(200) ,
        @sortDirect nvarchar(200) ,
        @TotalRows INT OUTPUT,
        @page INT ,
        @pagesize INT 
AS
BEGIN
    declare @result TABLE(OrderId nvarchar(50), OrderNumber nvarchar(50), CustomerName nvarchar(1000),
                    CustomerLocation nvarchar(1000), [Order] decimal, OrderDate DateTime, IsDebugOrder BIT,
                    OrderStatus int, OrderValidationResult int, CustomerEmail nvarchar(500), Zip nvarchar(100)
                    )

    ...

    select @TotalRows = count(*) from @result

    select *
    from @result 
END
```

it works fine except out parameter and I can't find where is error. It returns null every time. Could anyone help me with it?

Comment: Your out parameter but be an `ObjectParameter`.

Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192991/output-parameter-in-stored-procedure-in-ef

Comment: You are talking about using SP in DB First, and the same approach doesn't work in Code First.