# What is the type (none,scaler,entity,complex) if store procedure return multiple ouptput parameter in entity framework in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have created a mvc4 application with entity framework. Added a entity model in project. Now i have 
added a store procedure in model browser and editing import function. There is a option **Returns a collection of** which contains none,scalers,complex,entities. I am not able to decide which one to choose as my store procedure returns multiple output parameters. If it returns single parameter then i can choose scalers, if table then entities. But it returns more then one output parameter so which one to choose. I am attaching store procedure screen shot.[image][image]

Comment: you have to use `Complex`

Comment: but when i am selecting complex OK button got disabled

Comment: you have to click Get Column Information button and then click Create New Complex Type to create complex type which the SP returns

Comment: when i click it says The selected store procedure of function return no column.

Comment: instead of `*` you have return columns like  ID,Name, etc to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure uses reference parameters, but doesn't actually return anything. To make a stored procedure return something, end the procedure with a SELECT statement that doesn't set a variable.

So, your code with look something like this:

```
CREATE PROC [wickedbrains].[uspValidateAdminLogin]
@UserName   VARCHAR(50),
@Password   VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @UserId INT = NULL,
            @Res INT = 0;
    IF EXISTS(SELECT '' FROM tblAdminUser WHERE UserName = @UserName AND Pwd = @Password)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @UserId = Id FROM tblAdminUser WHERE UserName = @UserName AND Pwd = @Password;
        SET @Res = 1;
    END
    SELECT @UserId, @Res;
END
```

Once you've fixed your stored procedure, as Ehsan described, you can fix your imported stored procedure after the fact by clicking Get Column Information, then clicking Create New Complex Type.

If you absolutely have to use output parameters, you will have to retrieve the parameters with code as you would with reference parameters used in any other function. The point is that stored procedures that only use output parameters don't have a return type. See this answer for further details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6193419/12116036